# Incrementor not functioning

Tags: go, increment

I have some code which is supposed to increment a count.

Here is the struct containing the count variable:

```
type PipelineData struct {
    nodeData          map[string]map[string]int
    lastBurstResults  map[string]map[string]string
    burstReady        map[string]bool
    lastExecutionTime map[string]time.Time
    currentNodeSize  uint64
}
```

As you can see there is a member entitled `currentNodeSize`. This variable is intended to increment ever time the function `addNodeData` is called. You can see that the function `addNodeData` calls the function `addCount` which then uses an atomic incrementer.

```
func (p PipelineData) addNodeData(key string) {
    nodeSlot := clusterScenario.GetNodeSlotByHashSlot(key)
    i:=p.nodeData[nodeSlot][key]
    i++ 
    p.nodeData[nodeSlot][key]=i 
    p.addCount()
    fmt.Println("Adding node count ",p.currentNodeSize)
}

func (p PipelineData) addCount(){
    atomic.AddUint64(&p.currentNodeSize, 1) 
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this:

```
p.addNodeData("{pipelinetest}.key");
p.addNodeData("{pipelinetest}.key");
p.addNodeData("{pipelinetest}.key");
p.addNodeData("{pipelinetest}.key");
p.addNodeData("{pipelinetest}.key");    
p.addNodeData("{pipelinetest}.key");                
Dump(p.currentNodeSize)
```

The output is `0`.

Here is the initialization of the PipelineData struct:

```
p = &PipelineData{
  nodeData:make(map[string]map[string]int,0),
  lastBurstResults:make(map[string]map[string]string,0),
  burstReady:make(map[string]bool,0),
  lastExecutionTime:make(map[string]time.Time,0),
  currentNodeSize:0,
}
for i,_ := range clusterScenario.masterNodes{
    p.nodeData[i]=make(map[string]int,0)
}
```

I understand the community has asked me to do my research. I'm not sure what to do at the point. Any help would be appreciated.

**I also tried a general incrementor using a variable and that produced the same result which is why I tried an atomic incrementor**

Comment: You can't safely read the `currentNodeSize` value without also using atomic operations. There's no reason here however to use atomic operations, because the method calling `addCount` can't safely be used concurrently.

Comment: @JimB thanks for the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addCount` takes a value receiver, not a pointer, so it's operating on a copy of the struct, incrementing the field of the copy and then discarding the copy. Change it instead to take a pointer:

```
func (p *PipelineData) addCount(){
```

This should resolve your issue.